# Rails how to hide only default locale in url, but show others

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, url, routes, rails-i18n

Is it possible to hide the default locale in the url, but show the locale in the other languages?

Say, 'de' is my default locale, my login url should look like this:

```
domain.com/login
```

All the other login urls should show the language, e.g.:

```
domain.com/fr/login

domain.com/es/login
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

domain.com/login and domain.com/de/login are equivalent, if 'de' is the default_locale. So it is not necessary to hide the default locale. Either works.

Answer (score 1):

You should add this at your application_controller.rb:

```
def default_url_options   
  { locale: (I18n.locale unless I18n.locale == I18n.default_locale ) } 
end
```

Comment: This is a great answer to on old question!